# Open python shell in the current directory

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

I want to open python shell in the current directory like cmd. My system is windows 10. How can I achieve that?
Something like that:
    Suppose that I open a directory in D disk, let's say the path is "D:\PythonProjects". I tried to open cmd in current directory, in cmd I type
"python" to get python shell, but the work directory of python didn't chage.

Comment: Hmm...on my Linux mechine it works fine. However you could use `os.chdir()` to change the work directory.

Comment: What does "open a directory in D disk" mean?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I think he means: Opened a directory which in D disk via file manager, and then open a `cmd` there. (and enter the python shell, but the path still is `D:\\` . @real_actor am I right?)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do and what you're getting instead.

Comment: @Kevin Guan : you're right about what I sad. I'm not a native English speaker. But thank you. I just got my answer. The work directory of python had changed, but I didn't recognize it.

Comment: @real_actor: Don't worry, I'm also not :). However, if you think aliasm2k's answer is helpful, you can accept it. The button is on the right side of his answer, check our [tour] for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try something like this in command line?

```
C:> D:
D:> cd PythonProjects
D:\PythonProjects> python
[Something about Python interpreter]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it. I'm not native English speaker.

Comment: If the solution did help, do mark it as the answer.

Comment: You should find the button near the answer. I think. I haven't asked any questions yet. So, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply open shell
and than

```
import os
os.chdir(" ")
```

In between quotes you can specify path were you want to open that

You can also see current path by

```
os.getcwd()
```